# JS eventListener equivalent in VB 2010

Tags: javascript, vb.net, event-listener

I have this problem: I need to be able to catch changed in DOM elements in a page that I am loading in a Visual Basic webBrowser control. Normally in JavaScript in Firefox I would do something like this: element[0].childNodes[1].addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", functionX, true); where element[0] is the element that I need monitored and child[1] is the 2nd child for this element that has its text value changed which I need to catch when it changes, while functionX is the function/sub that I want to trigger everytime there is a change in element[0].childNodes[1].

I can do this easily in JavaScript but I am having a terrible time implementing this in Visual Basic 2010 in a webbrowser control that I use to implement a browser.

I know that there is something like Dim del As New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.CallGlobalJSMethod) but I am having a difficult time implementing this practically. Does anyone have any idea how this can be done practically?

Update: I am opening a page in a webbrowser control in VB2010 like this: WebBrowser1.Navigate(address.Text) then monitor the page.
On this webpage there is a text field with id "ctrlid". This control's text property changes periodically. I need to catch the event when changes and react to it.

Comment: Need a bit more clarification on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I asked this question 3 wks ago. I did figure out the answer meanwhile and I am documenting it here, in case someone else needs help.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question 3 wks ago. I did figure out the answer meanwhile and I am documenting it here, in case someone else needs help. The problem was with the `OnChange` event. The correct event trigger method is `OnPropertyChange` for the webbrowser control to fire up events on changes for elements hosted on its navigated to page. This is a working example which I am pasting from a different VB forums where I asked the same question and finalized the answer:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

   Dim doc As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
   Dim aC As HtmlElement = doc.GetElementById("previewclock")
   Try
       If aC Is Nothing Then Return
       aC.AttachEventHandler("onpropertychange", AddressOf SomethingChanged)
   Catch
   End Try
```

and then a separate sub routine where the 'fired' event is processed:

```
Private Sub SomethingChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'MsgBox("Event was captured!")
        Console.WriteLine(Now.ToLongTimeString & ":" & "Changed")
End Sub
```